# Получение файлов

Tags: c#

Всем привет, в C# есть метов: BeginSendFile с его помощью можно отправлять файлы, а как-же принимать их? Я метода не нашёл... Как можно получить файл?

Answer (score 3):

Парная функция должна быть [BeginReceive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxkwh6zw.aspx). Вы получите данные, а уж с записью их в файл, думаю, проблем не должно быть.